The name of a 1950s movie about flight to Mars
I watched it several years ago on youtube and it was rather entertaining. 
It's in colour, could be 1960s/70s, but I remember it being 1950s.
What I remember is that there is a military base orbiting the Moon. Then a visitor arrives from Earth and orders a crew to fly to Mars. They reach Mars, land on it, but had troubles taking off because of the landscape and problems with fuel. No Martian life encounter. Also one of the crew members manages to plant a plant.
I couldn't find it on the list of Mars movies

Sounds like Conquest of Space from 1955.

Mankind has achieved the capability of space flight and built "The Wheel", a space station in orbit 1,075 miles above Earth. The station is commanded by its designer, Colonel Samuel T. Merritt (Walter Brooke). [...] The space station's personnel have been building a giant spaceship in a nearby orbit. An inspector arrives from Earth by shuttle with new orders: Not only is Merritt being promoted to General, but the new spaceship is being sent to Mars under his command.

They encounter many problems on Mars, including the rocket springing a leak due to sabotage by one of the crew members, but no aliens. And one crew member plants a seed in the Martian soil and it grows into a flower. Here's the trailer:




I thought for a 1955 movie it had very good special effects
